# Reference to a hash of a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following code:

```
my $hhref = {'ancient' => {'Adam' => 'Eve',
                          'Antony' => 'Cleopatra'}, 
             'modern' => {'Clyde' => 'Bonnie'}};
print "$hhref->{'ancient'}{'Antony'}\n";
```

Which prints out:

```
REF(0x35c320)Cleopatra
```

And I really don't understand why. Why doesn't it just print `Cleopatra`?

Comment: Does it really print `REF(0x35c320)`? I've never seen Perl print a reference preceded with "REF". Usually, it would be the type of reference - "HASH", "ARRAY" or something like that.

Comment: On every version of Perl I have tested it on, this code does the right thing. I get no extra reference displayed. If you run just this code, does it still display that extra reference? I think that output is generated by other code that you are not showing us. If this code (and only this code) generates the output you show, then please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40231134/edit) to add the Perl version and operating system that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of perl and which OS you are using you will get slightly different results.  The trouble really comes from having quotes in your print statement.  If instead your code was

```
my $hhref = {'ancient' => {'Adam' => 'Eve',
                      'Antony' => 'Cleopatra'}, 
         'modern' => {'Clyde' => 'Bonnie'}};
print $hhref->{'ancient'}{'Antony'};
print "\n";
```

then it will print correctly.  Why?  Well, perl has trouble understanding what you mean.  Do you mean "$hhref" followed by "->{'ancient'}{'Antony'}", or do you mean "$hhref->{'ancient'}" followed by "{'ancient'}", or is it all together as one variable?  Outside of a string the compiler is exact but inside a string it has to make guesses at what you mean because white space is used differently and not deterministically like it is in code.

Basically, if you want variables to be interpreted correctly every time then reference them outside of quotes in perl.

Comment: @Gambit2007 That behavior is mentioned in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs), in the "Interpolation" paragraph : the words "most of the time", "heuristic estimators", "not strictly predictable" and "usually correct" speak for themselves!

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me. Given that it is printing "Cleopatra", Perl is clearly walking the data structure correctly. The `REF(0x35c320)` must be generated by code that we aren't seeing here. The documentation you have pointed to is about parsing text in operators like `s///` - it has nothing to do with this current situation.